# What is the name for comments with '@' in them?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide, doxygen

This is a case of not being able to look something up because I don't know the name for it. In many code editors you can include these in the preceding comment block of a definition and then get helpful mouse-over text elsewhere, or other programs can read these comments and do something useful with them. I'm working on a file related to Doxygen. For example:

```
    /// AskStackOverflow() - Gets answer to a question
    /// @name AskStackOverflow
    /// @brief Ask Stack Overflow
    /// @param q Question to be asked 
    /// @return Number of up votes for this cheeky comment
    int AskStackOverFlow(std::string q)
    {
       /* Some great computer codes*/
       return 1234687624;
    }
```

What is the name for this sort of comment?
Bonus question: These are not (typically) a feature of any language but a UI/UX feature of the IDE such as Visual Studio, correct?

Comment: A bit of an abstract question, in my opinion you should give a more explicit example tell where in your opinion the problem lies in the given example. Best is always to browse through / read the available documentation.

Comment: Shouldn't be too abstract, the thing has to have a name after all. Initially I hadn't considered that it could have been related to Doxygen, I can update the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but `@q` it looks like you want to document the argument `q` of the rountine., the syntax for this is not `@q` in doxygen but you should use here `@param q`.

Comment: Ok that's helpful! I'm not always sure what I want either :p

Comment: Sometimes I have the same problem as I don't know the name of a command, but browsing through / reading the available documentation does help most of the time and otherwise one has to write an explicit question on stackoverflow. (seen the later I wonder quite a bit why you accepted the answer given as it contains hardly information only a link to one chapter of the doxygen documentation. It is, for me also strange that people upvoted the  answer)>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is Doxygen **markdown**

https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html

Comment: Can you tell why OP might be looking for markdown and e.g. not for the name of a command used?